# Nativescript android search bar not showing with list view

Tags: android, angularjs, nativescript

The issue with android search bar and list view while using with grid layout and stack layout. The search bar shows when list view is commented

```
  Action Bar Here
    <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar">
        <ActionItem (tap)="showModal()"
        ios.systemIcon="4" ios.position="left"
        android.systemIcon="ic_menu_add" android.position="actionBar"></ActionItem>

    </ActionBar>
```

Grid Layout with scrollview

```
                <StackLayout class="form">
                        <SearchBar [formControl]="searchControl" class="input"></SearchBar>
                    </StackLayout>

            <ListView [items]="_batches" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)" class="list-group">

                <ng-template let-comment="item" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" let-even="even">
                    <!-- The item template can only have a single root view container (e.g. GridLayout, StackLayout, etc.)-->
                    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="list-group-item" ><StackLayout width="200" height="45">
                                    <Label  horizontalAlignment="left" [text]="comment.title" textWrap="true" ></Label>
                                    <Label  horizontalAlignment="left" [text]="comment.title" textWrap="true"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout width="60">
                                    <Button  horizontalAlignment="right" class="edit-button" text="" (tap)="EditItem(comment.id)"></Button>
                            </StackLayout> 
                            <StackLayout  horizontalAlignment="right" width="60">
                                    <Button class="delete-button" text="" (tap)="DeleteItem(comment.id)"></Button>
                            </StackLayout> 



                    </StackLayout>

                </ng-template>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollView>
    </GridLayout>  </pre>
```

Comment: you need to explain your issue more with code also

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari Updated have a look.

Answer (score 0):

It's your layout, learn more about using layouts at https://www.nslayouts.com/

```
<GridLayout rows="auto,*">
    <StackLayout row="0" class="form">
        <SearchBar [formControl]="searchControl" class="input"></SearchBar>
    </StackLayout>
    <ListView row="1" [items]="_batches" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)" class="list-group">
        <ng-template let-comment="item" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" let-even="even">
            <!-- The item template can only have a single root view container (e.g. GridLayout, StackLayout, etc.)-->
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="list-group-item">
                <StackLayout width="200" height="45">
                    <Label horizontalAlignment="left" [text]="comment.title" textWrap="true"></Label>
                    <Label horizontalAlignment="left" [text]="comment.title" textWrap="true"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout width="60">
                    <Button horizontalAlignment="right" class="edit-button" text=""
                        (tap)="EditItem(comment.id)"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout horizontalAlignment="right" width="60">
                    <Button class="delete-button" text="" (tap)="DeleteItem(comment.id)"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

The code above should give you a fixed Search Bar at top with a scrollable ListView. If you still have issues, please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.